# alterqcm package: Is there a way to individualize enumeration?

Tags: enumerate, alterqcm

Is there a way to individualize the enumeration in the alterqcm package? I couldn't find a proper option in the documentation. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alterqcm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alterqcm}[lq=100mm,language=english,numstyle=\alph] 
 \AQquestion{Question1}{% 
 {A},
 {B}}  
\AQquestion{Question 2}{% 
 {A},
 {B}} 
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

I would like to replace the enumeration in the Questions column (a., b.) by a.) and b.).

Is there some hack to extend the enumeration options? It would be great to include the flexibility of the enumerate package. 
More precisely, instead of 
[image]

I would like to have
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question? Can you explain what result you want? Or you just want to change the method of asking the question and in this case the answer is no!

Comment: @AlainMatthes I have added some pictures clarifying the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly solution

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AQquestion}[3][]{%
\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
\stepcounter{AQ@numquestion}% 
\setcounter{AQ@numprop}{0} % v0.93
\setcounter{aq@numb}{0}%
\@for\liste:=#3\do{%
\stepcounter{aq@numb}%
\begingroup
\ifnum\aqlocall@ng=3 \nogreekalph\fi
\global\expandafter\let\csname aq@arg\alph{aq@numb}\endcsname\liste
\endgroup}%
\ifAQ@global@alea\ifAQ@global@VF
\else
\aq@n@arg=0 %
\loop\ifnum\aq@n@arg<\value{aq@numb}\aq@melange\advance\aq@n@arg by1\repeat\fi
\fi
\aq@adjust{#2}%
\multirow{1}{\cmdAQ@global@lq}[\cmdAQ@local@pq]{%
\ifAQ@global@num\aq@style@numquest{\cmdAQ@global@numstyle{AQ@numquestion}.)}%    
% the change is in the line above 
\hspace{3pt}\fi
\ifAQ@global@transparent%
\hrule height0pt depth0pt width\aq@wdquest%
\else
#2\vss
\fi
 }%
&\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
      \aq@prop{\aq@arga}{1}\\%
      \ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi
&\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
      \aq@prop{\aq@argb}{2}\\
      \ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi
      \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=2\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi
&\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
      \aq@prop{\aq@argc}{3}\\
      \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=3\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi
&\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
      \aq@prop{\aq@argd}{4}\\
      \ifnum\value{aq@numb}=4\hline\else\ifAQ@global@sep\cline{2-2}\fi
&\setkeys[AQ]{local}{#1}%
     \aq@prop{\aq@arge}{5}\\
\hline\fi\fi\fi}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{alterqcm}[lq=100mm,language=english,numstyle=\alph] 
 \AQquestion{Question1}{% 
 {A},
 {B}}  
\AQquestion{Question 2}{% 
 {A},
 {B}} 
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

[image]